# Facebook Share Dialog is not opening

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-share

As per this [link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/), I have installed the SDK 3.2.1 and implemented a uiHelper, along with FacebookDialog like this:

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(),
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
        // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(
                this).setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Fallback. For example, publish the post using the Feed Dialog
        publishFeedDialog();
    }
```

For `publishFeedDialog()` I have:

```
    private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption",
            "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString(
            "description",
            "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture",
            "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
            Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }

            }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Now the `FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog` is always going to false even when Fb app is installed in the phone and then the publishFeedDialog() is called. But the app crashes after this.

What is the solution for this? Why is the normal facebook dialog shown when the app is there in my phone? (I am using Lenevo model, if that helps)

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have? canPresentShareDialog will only return true for versions of the FB app that support it.

Comment: I just checked, it is 2.2.1 and playstore says the current version is 24.X! I guess that should solve the issue. Let me get back to you later. Thanks.

Comment: `This works!` The dialog comes up with my link and description, `BUT` when I hit the share button, a facebook notification comes up saying `"Something went wrong, please try again"`

Comment: I believe the problem was that the app was not published to general public by facebook. Apparently there's a bunch of reviews before that can be done. I believe the question is answered, if you would kindly put that comment in answer, I would gladly accept that as one. Also, can you tell me if the Login screen is necessary even when the requirement is just populating the status field when share button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newer FB app in order for the share dialog to work. Make sure you download the latest ones!

Also, no, you don't need login to enable the share dialog.

Comment: If you see my previous comment on the question, the current issue is Facebook wants to review my app before I can make it open to general public and use that share dialog feature. For that, one of the required thing is to provide Login screen.

Comment: You don't need approval to use the Share Dialog, it's not one of the options in the submission.

Comment: How can I populate the status field when I show the user the share dialog? I know link is set using .setLink()

Comment: You cannot populate the status field, the user MUST type that in themselves.